# What does it mean for a curve to be homothetic to another?

Tags: terminology

What does it mean for one curve to be **homothetic** (< Greek *θετικός*, < *τιθέναι* to place) to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadamard's [*Lessons in Geometry: I. Plane Geometry*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6631) (bk. 3, ch. 5 "Homothecy & Similarity", p. 145) defines "homothecy":

> **140.** Definition. If we choose a point *S* as the *center of homothecy*, and a number $k$ called the *ratio of homothecy* or *ratio of similarity*, the homothetic image of an arbitrary point *M* is the point *M'* obtained by joining *SM* and taking a segment *SM* on this line or on its extension, starting from *S* (Fig. 136), such that $\frac{SM'}{SM}=k$.
>
> [image: figures 136 & 137]
>
> The homothecy is said to be *direct* if *SM'* is taken in the sense of *SM* (fig. 136.) and *inverse* if these segments are in opposite senses (Fig. 137). The *homothetic image* of a figure *F* is the figure formed by the set of all points *M'*, homothetic to the points which constitute the figure *F*.

---

Lo Bello's [*Origins of Mathematical Words*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6132) p. 164 says:

> **homothetic** See the entry **homo-** above. The word *homothetic* is a
>   modern invention created on the analogy of adjectives like *synthetic*
>   from the verb [**τίθημι**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CF%84%CE%AF%CE%B8%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%B9&la=greek#lexicon), *to put or place*. The associated adjective is
>   [**θετικός**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CE%B8%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82&la=greek#lexicon), which means *fit for placing, apposite, positive*. A homothetic
>   function of the plane is a dilation or contraction followed by a
>   translation, that is, a function that takes $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ where $u = h + λx$ and $v = k + λy$, where $h$, $k$, and $λ$ are arbitrary real numbers. The idea intended is that geometric figures are placed in the same position
>   relative to one another after the application of the homothetic
>   function as they were before. However, the adjective [**θετικός**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CE%B8%CE%B5%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CF%8C%CF%82&la=greek#lexicon) never
>   meant *placed*, which was [**τιθείς**](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%B8%CE%B5%CE%AF%CF%82&la=greek#lexicon).

Answer (score 1):

A *[homothety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation)* is a map $f:\>{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}^n$ that can be described in the form
$$f:\quad{\bf x}\to {\bf a}+\lambda{\bf x}$$
for some ${\bf a}\in{\mathbb R}^n$ and $\lambda\ne0$. The set ${\cal H}$ of these maps does not depend on a chosen basis, nor on a scalar product (euclidean metric) which might be present in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

It follows that two curves $\gamma$, $\gamma'\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ are homothetic if they are similar under a similarity $f:\>{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^2$ leaving directions invariant.